# Volume of a set E

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have a set $E=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R ^3:0<y<\pi,z^2+(x-y^5)^2<\sin y\}$ and I want to calculate the volume.
Can I use a transformation of coordinates?

Comment: What is the range of $x$? Is it $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @H. It is all x such that the second inequality makes sense.

Comment: You should not use any transformation of coordinates as it will get a complicated mess in the middle. instead, follow the hint in @Justpassingby answer which unwind the obfuscation which intentionally introduced to this question. After you do that, you can basically integrate the integral inside your head.

Answer (score 1):

For constant $y$ the integral over $x$ and $z$ is the area of a disk with radius the square root of the sine of $y.$ You could make that more explicit in polar coordinates around the point $(x=y^5,z=0).$

The remaining $y$ integral is then

$$\int_{y=0}^\pi\pi\sin y\ dy=2\pi.$$

Comment: Does this suggest the "transformation of coordinates" that the OP asks about using?

Comment: I don't understand how make the change of coordinates

Comment: Replace $x$ and $z$ with $r$ and $\theta$ Such that $x=y^5+r\cos\theta$ and $z=r\sin\theta.$

Comment: the result is $2\pi$?

Comment: That's what I got, too.